# Show that B is a tight frame if and only iff $\sum_{j=1}^N \|v_j\|^2e^{2i\theta_j}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

1. Let $B=\{ v_0, \dots, v_k \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume $v_0=(1,0)$. Let $\theta_i$ be the angle formed by $v_i$ and $v_0$. Show that B is a tight frame if and only iff $$\sum_{j=1}^N \|v_j\|^2e^{2i\theta_j}=0$$ Hint: Let $v_j=(r_j\,cos\theta_j,r_j\,sin\theta_j) \dots$
2. Use the previous identity to show that the vertices of a regular polygon with n sides inscribed in a circle of radius 1 form a tight frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

A tight frame is if the rows of the matrix are orthogonal to each other and have the same length. Also $$\|v\|^2=c^2 \sum_{i=1}^k \langle x,v_i \rangle^2$$ if B is tight.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $v_i=\{ \begin{bmatrix} r_j\cos(\theta_j) \\ r_j\sin(\theta_j) \end{bmatrix} \}_{j=1}^k$ Then $$\sum_{j=1}^k \|v_j\|^2e^{2i\theta_j}= \sum_{j=1}^k r^2_j(\cos(2\theta_j) +i\sin(2\theta_j))$$

$\Rightarrow$: Assume B is tight then

$$ \|(1,\dots,|r_k|\cos\theta_j)| =\|(0,\dots, |r_k|\sin\theta_j)\|  \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2(\cos^2\theta_j-\sin^2\theta_j)=0=\sum_{j=1}^kr_j^2\cos(2\theta_j)$$

$$\langle (1,\dots,|r_j|\cos\theta_j),(0,\dots, |r_j|\sin\theta_j) \rangle =0 \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2(\cos\theta_j\sin\theta_j)=0=\sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2sin(2\theta_j)=-\sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2isin(2\theta_i)$$

From these two equations we have:
$$-\sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2i\sin(2\theta_i)=\sum_{j=1}^kr_j^2\cos(2\theta_j) \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^N r^2_j(\cos(2\theta_j) +i\sin(2\theta_j))=0$$

$\Leftarrow$: Assume that the following is true: $$\sum_{j=1}^k \|v_j\|^2e^{2i\theta_j}=\sum_{j=1}^k r^2_j(\cos(2\theta_j) +i\sin(2\theta_j))=0$$
We are going to show that B is a tight frame by proof by contradiction.

Let $p=\sum_{j=1}^kr_j^2\cos(2\theta_j)$, where $0 \neq p \in \mathbb{R}$, and $q=\sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2\sin(2\theta_i)$, where $0 \neq q \in \mathbb{R}$.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\sum_{j=1}^k r_j^2isin(2\theta_i)=\sum_{j=1}^kr_j^2\cos(2\theta_j) & \Rightarrow  p=-iq \\
& \Rightarrow (p+0i)=(0-iq) \\
& \Rightarrow (p+0)+(0-q)i=0 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

This is only true if $p,q=0$, which is a contradiction.

How would I prove part 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he vertices of a regular polygon with n sides  have coordinates in the form of $(\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n}), \sin(\frac{2\pi k}{n}))z$, where $k=0,\dots,n$. Having the knowledge from part a, we can do the following:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_{j=1}^k (\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{k}) +i\sin(\frac{2\pi j}{k})) & =\sum_{j=1}^k e^{\frac{2\pi ij}{k}} \\
& =\frac{1-e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{k}}}{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}} \\
& =\frac{1-1}{1-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}} \\
& =0 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}